# culling values in csv.DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I'm working with a huge csv that I am parsing with csv.DictReader , what would be some most efficient way to trim the data in the resulting dictionary based on the key name .
Say, just keep the keys that contain "JAN" .

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
result = {key:val for key, val in row.items() if 'JAN' in key}
```

where `row` is a dictionary obtained from `DictReader`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> with open('file.csv') as f:
...   culled = [{k: d[k] for k in d if "JAN" in k} for d in csv.DictReader(f)]
```

When I tried this on a simple CSV file with the following contents:

```
JAN11,FEB11,MAR11,APR11,MAY11,JUN11,JUL11,AUG11,SEP11,OCT11,NOV11,DEC11,JAN12,FEB12,MAR12,APR12
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
```

I got the following result:

```
>>> with open('file.csv') as f:
...   culled = [{k: d[k] for k in d if "JAN" in k} for d in csv.DictReader(f)]
... 
>>> culled
[{'JAN11': '1', 'JAN12': '13'}, {'JAN11': '17', 'JAN12': '29'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a dirt stupid example of using csv.DictReader with `/etc/passwd`

```
#!python
keepers = dict()
r = csv.DictReader(open('/etc/passwd', 'r'), delimiter=":", \
      fieldnames=('login','pw', 'uid','gid','gecos','homedir', 'shell'))
for i in r:
    if i['uid'] < 1:
        continue
    keepers[i['login']]=i
```

Now, trying to apply that to your question ... I'm only guessing that you were building a dictionary of dictionaries based on the phrase "from the resulting dictionary."  It seems obvious that the read/object is going to return a dictionary for every input record.  So there will be one resulting dictionary for every line of your file (assuming any of the common CSV "dialects").

Naturally I could have used `if i['uid'] > 1` or `if "Jan" in i['gecos']` and only added to my "keepers" if the condition holds true.  I wrote it this way to emphasize how you can easily skip those values in which you're not interested, such that the rest of your `for` suite could do various interesting things with those records that are of interest.

However, this answer is so simple that I have to suspect that I'm not understanding the question. (I'm using ''/etc/passwd'' and a colon separated list simply because it's an extremely well known format and world-readable copies are readily available on Linux, Unix, and MacOS X systems).